# Processing Image for machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, scikit-image

I started to do the medical image analysis for a project.

In this project I have images of human kidney(s) with and without stones. The aim is to predict if the given new image has stone or not.

I chose the KNN classifier model to do classification but I do not understand the image processing. I have some knowledge on segmentation. I can convert it into array for processing but I need some pointers to understand the process. 
Image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FDUM.jpg

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Asking for pointers to general explanations is specifically off topic.

Comment: Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues

Answer (score 0):

For image classification I would recommend you to use pre-trained neural networks like Resnet etc.

Frameworks like Tensorflow give a good API to re-train pre-trainined neural networks for a different use-case.

You can follow below link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining

Answer (score 0):

Image Processing is done to convert the digital images into a format which would be easier for a computer to calculate statistics on.

Images do not always contain the necessary information, there is noise and lots of unnecessary background information available in the image which won't be required for a specific purpose.

The Goal of processing an image is to extract the region of interest from the whole image.

Along with this various enhancements are done to the image so that we get features that are useful in calculating inferences

Processing an image consists of various image enhancement techniques and segmentation and other stuff like maybe a histogram equalization which in the end would be used to extract features. Doing this processing yields better features generally.

Also Image processing in itself is a vast topic. I recommend you read about it in papers from Google scholar